# Switch Xamarin forms app with another app

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I need to launch another 3rd party's app from my app and after performing certain operation need to switch back to my app again.
Soon after launching the other app there will be a call to a web service which will return the result related to the operation done with 3rd party app.
I could able to launch the 3rd party app but remaining part is to switching back to my app after web service return.

Is there a way I can get this done?

Thanks

Dhakau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use app linking (even called deep linking)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/app-linking
https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/cross-platform/app-links/app-links-ios